# Get all users who have reacted to message, Discord Python

Tags: python, discord.py

I saw a previous answer, sadly it was not in Discord's rewrite.
I've tried doing many different things, nothing has worked so far.

```
@bot.command()
async def kickroulette(ctx):
    message = await ctx.send("React here!")
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    user = random.choice(users who have reacted)
    await ctx.guild.kick(user)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fetch the message again with it's ID to get new reactions.

```py
@bot.command()
async def kickroulette(ctx):
    message = await ctx.send("React here!")
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    msg = await ctx.channel.fetch_message(message.id)
    reactors = await msg.reactions[0].users().flatten()
    user = random.choice(reactors)
    await ctx.guild.kick(user)
```